# SQL Finding codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see all my customers who have received a document code Eg. [RF001], however I also want to see that they haven't received a number of document codes E.G [RF002, RF005, RF006, RF009].
All the document codes sit in 1 column, and the customer references are repeated.

```
Table 

Customer_Ref | Doc_Code
CS001 | RF001
CS002 | RF003
CS001 | RF002
```

Code thats been tried is;

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_Data
WHERE Doc_Code = RF001
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? One of those tags are extraneous

Comment: It is SQL Server........

Comment: Please add the SQL you wrote that is not producing the correct output.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have you misread, I don't think he means the codes are in the same row per customer - atomic values in multiple rows is fine

Comment: @Stu the original question showed everything in the same row

Comment: Ah ok I must have not seen an earlier edit :)

Comment: This will be an easy solution, just needs some proper sample data and the expected output in the question.

Comment: Somewhere you need to have a complete list of "all customers". Some of your current answers make an assumption but fail to highlight this important fact. This is made more difficult with the use of anonymous table names - including your own. If you don't have a true list of "all customers" the best you can do is generate it from your existing table by selecting all distinct Customer_Ref values. As always, be careful what you assume and make sure you understand your actual goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude unwanted results :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 tbl
WHERE
    Doc_Code='RF001'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Table1 unwanted
                    WHERE 
                        tbl.Customer_Ref=unwanted.Customer_Ref
                        AND Doc_Code IN ('RF002', 'RF005', 'RF006', 'RF009'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_Data t1
WHERE t1.Doc_Code = 'RF001'
and not exists (select 1 from Test_Data t2 
                where t1.Customer_Ref = t2.Customer_Ref 
                and t2.Doc_Code in ('RF002', 'RF005', 'RF006', 'RF009')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to accomplish this.

This is but one way using a join

```
SELECT Distinct A.CUSTOMER_REF
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISINTCT CUSTOMER_REF 
           FROM TABLE B
           WHERE B.DOC_CODE IN ('RF002', 'RF005', 'RF006', 'RF009') B
 ON A.CUSTOMER_REF = B.CUSTOMER_REF
WHERE A.DOC_CODE = 'RF001'
and B.Customer_REF is null
```

- Another way is to use not exists (I'm sure someone else will do)
- Another way is to use a not in (I'm sure someone else will do)
- Another way is to use set logic and EXCEPT (Similar to a Union; but subtracts once set from another)

.

```
SELECT A.Customer_REF FROM table where DOC_CODE = 'RF001'
EXCEPT
SELECT A.Customer_REF FROM Table where DOC_CODE IN ('RF002', 'RF005', 'RF006', 'RF009')
```

Comment: @charlieface  bah MINUS Oracle/mySQL Except SQL SERVER & Postgrel  thanks